# SignalR shows no output on Front end of a site

Tags: signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am a beginner in SignalR. I have used the source code given on internet. I retrieve data from database and then pass it on to next function which further passes it onto client side function. My client side function is not executing. So nothing is printed. Client side code is this:

```
var notifyFriends = $.connection.friends;
notifyFriends.client.displayFriendsOnline = function (msg)
{$('#chatbox').html(msg);};
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Comment: Basically my code does not executes the inner function that is notifyFriends.client.displayFriendsOnline = function (msg)
{
 $('#chatbox').html(msg);
};
It does not enter in this. Why is so? Please, let me know.

Comment: information not enough! can you post your server side codes?  I would suggest you create a simple client and simple server first.  e.g. client calls server method a, inside Server method a calls client method b, in client method b, alert something from method b parms.